# What's the benefit of using multiple measurement threads?

Tags: jmh

I just noticed that JMH allows us to use multiple measurement threads (by default, only one thread is used).

What's the point of using multiple measurement threads? Is it only meant to test thread contention in the code being benchmarked? Or will the benchmarks complete any sooner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads in JMH are about testing concurrent code on a microbenchmark-level, for example if you want to compare a lock to using compare-and-swap against a shared resource.

In general, JMH needs to run code sufficiently often to for example trigger JIT compilation but in my understanding this would rather be a side-effect. If your application is single-threaded and you run a multithreaded benchmark, it would not be representative of your application even if it ran faster.